# .net framework c# web api, send username and password as string array in body from postman

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, postman, .net-framework-version

I tried below code to read username/password from body, but all i am getting is 'object reference not set to an instance of an object'
Code of API:
[image: postman image]

```
[Route("api/login_test")]
[HttpGet]
public object login_test([FromBody] string[] Username_Password])
{
    string UsernameOrEmail_address, Password;
    UsernameOrEmail_address = Username_Password[0];
    Password = Username_Password[1];

    return UsernameOrEmail_address  + " " + Password;
}
```

Comment: Username_Password is probably null

Comment: yes, but how i send it as not null? from post man or from other application where i will include my request, to understand the method i will include it into the body

Comment: Also you have  a typo. "[FromBody string[] Username_Password] " should be "[FromBody] string[] Username_Password"

Comment: Also if you are expecting a body HttpPost is probably more correct

Comment: so the issue, is because i am using HttpGet? i changed the typo above, my mistake

Comment: You tell me. What happens when you make it a HttpPost?

Comment: WOW thanks a lot Shanie, I have been hitting my head on the wall for that, the change of the request from HttpGet to HttpPost worked like a charm, thank you very much, you saved my day :)

Comment: No problem. You should probably read up on those Http Methods. They're each used for different situations. Google it. It's a 20 min read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by Changing the Http request it worked, *replacing from HttpGet* to **HttpPost**

```
[Route("api/login_test")]
[HttpPost]
public object login_test([FromBody] string[] Username_Password])
{
    string UsernameOrEmail_address, Password;
    UsernameOrEmail_address = Username_Password[0];
    Password = Username_Password[1];

    return UsernameOrEmail_address  + " " + Password;
}
```