# Async task HttpPost request DoInbackground call web api Android Studio Java, how to add body string array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, android-asynctask

I am trying to send a raw body request Array, any idea how to implement the Body array string, in java android studio?

Web API .net framework c# working:

```
[Route("api/login_test")]
[HttpPost]
public object login_test([FromBody] string[] Username_Password])
{
    string UsernameOrEmail_address, Password;
    UsernameOrEmail_address = Username_Password[0];
    Password = Username_Password[1];

    return UsernameOrEmail_address  + " " + Password;
}
```

Below what i am trying to achieve, this also as a reference,[web api c# test on postman and working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66151850/net-framework-c-sharp-web-api-send-username-and-password-as-string-array-in-bo) Java Async Task from android studio:

```
   /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class login_test extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        HttpURLConnection conn = null ;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            try {
                URL url_login;

                url_login = new URL(url_api + "login_test");
             
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url_login.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               


                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                jsonArray.put(0, username);
                jsonArray.put(1,  password);

                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                osw.write(String.valueOf(jsonArray));

                Log.i("Body to API", String.valueOf(jsonArray));
                osw.flush();
                osw.close();
}

}

}
```

I tried above, but it is not success because somehow it is not being written right, and i am getting exception as it fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue, I had to a Content-Type as application/json

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
```